# jquery keep selecting same iframe

Tags: jquery

I have some iframes that are created with jquery each iframe has a select button, but when i  click the button from that iframe i keep getting the first iframe.

```
 $("<iframe />" , {
    src: strTest,
    id: "myframe",
    width: '100%'       

}).appendTo('.content');
$("<button/>", {

  id: "button"
})
.text("Select Patient")    
.click(function () {     
  $("#myframe").attr("Height", "125%").addClass("selectedIframe");        
  var isVisible = $("selectedIframe").is(":visible");      

}).appendTo('.content');  

$(".selectedIframe").parent().show();
```

can somebody help me please. thanks

Comment: Try making the id's unique for each iframe.

Comment: hi scrappedcola, thanks for the advised, how can i add a unique id is there a reference thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to come up with your own way of adding a unique characteristic next to 'myframe'
or you can just give me some info on how you come up with the iframes and perhaps i can provide some more assistance

```
    // this will generate 10 iframes
    var numberOfIframes = 10;
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfIframes; i++) {

        // iframe
        $("<iframe />", {
            src: strTest,
            id: "myframe" + i,
            width: '100%'
        }).appendTo('.content');

        // button
        $("<button/>", {

            id: "button"
        })
        .text("Select Patient")
        .click(function () {
            $("#myframe" + i).attr("Height", "125%").addClass("selectedIframe");
            var isVisible = $("selectedIframe").is(":visible");
        }).appendTo('.content');
    }

    // not sure what you are trying to achieve with this
    // as it will only execute once when the page loads
    $(".selectedIframe").parent().show();
```

Comment: thank you ted for your your answer, but when i use this then button doesn't select any iframe

Comment: was it selecting it before? I can't be sure of the syntax, you haven't supplied any of your html

Comment: no when i use this it select the button instead of the iframe

Comment: you're right. sorry about that, I am correcting it now. however, you still haven't told me how you're coming up with the iframe. isn't there some unique characteristic which you can concat to each "myFrame"?